# What is this notation (series)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I'm asked to show the convergence or divergence of the following series using the ratio test:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdot\cdot\cdot (3k-2)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot\cdot\cdot (2k)}$$

What does the "$\cdot\cdot\cdot$" represent, and how would I go about applying the ratio test to such a series (which is, of course, 'trivial' for something less.. obscure(?)) ?

Comment: It just means that the product is repeated.   The numerator is the product of the numbers $1$ more than a multiple of $3$ from $1$ to $3k-2$.  The denominator is similar.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If
$$a_k=\frac{1.4.7.10....(3k-2)}{2.4.6.8...(2k)}$$

then

$$a_{k+1}=\frac{1.4...(3k-2)(3(k+1)-2)}{2.4....(2k)(2(k+1))}$$

Answer (score 0):

$...$ is used to imply some sort of pattern.

On the numerator, the meaning of $ 1\cdot 4\cdot 7\dots(3k-2)$ means the product of all numbers $1$ more than a multiple of $3$, ending at $3k-2$. For example when $k=5$ it is the product $1\cdot4\cdot7\cdot10\cdot13.$

Similarly $ 2\cdot 4\cdot 6\dots(2k)$ would be the product of even numbers up to a certain point. For $k=5$ it would be $2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdot10$.

Applying the ratio test should be pretty simple given that the top and bottom both have $k$ terms in the product.